# Compile error when using cout to output result of bitwise operator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-precedence

I can do this `int c= 0xF^0xF; cout << c;`

But `cout << 0xF^0xF;` won't compile. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator<<` has higher precedence than `operator^`, so `cout << 0xF^0xF;` is equivalent with:

```
(cout << 0xF) ^ 0xF;
```

`cout << 0xF` returns `cout` (i.e. a `std::ostream`), which can't be used as the operand of `operator^`.

You could add parentheses to specify the correct precedence:

```
cout << (0xF ^ 0xF);
```

Comment: Thanks songyuanyao. Out of curiosity, why does `<<` have higher precedence than bitwise operators, but not arithmetic operators, like "+"?For example, I can do `cout << 2+3;` with no problems.

Comment: @Bist Because the holy standard says so. :) Anyway, even `cout << 2+3;` works as you expect, you still should use parentheses. It makes your intent clearer, and could avoid subtle bugs. Let's all (code readers and code writer) stop meaningless guesses.

Comment: @Bist Bitwise operators `^ | &` have lower precendence than the value arithmetic operators `+ - * / << >>`  . Originally `<<` was the left-shift operator, in a similar category to multiplication. So you might write `1 << 3 | 1 << 2` or `1 << 3 ^ 1 << 2`.   Then when `<<` got co-opted as stream extraction operator, the precedence did not get changed because that would be even more confusing.

Comment: @M.M Is it relevant with the C heritage?

Comment: @songyuanyao first rule of standard, don't break the existing code, keep everything consistent. Even the old C++ code also has that bit mask